# Automatically execute Sphinx on Python script using Jenkins

Tags: python, windows, jenkins, python-sphinx

I have been trying to create a Jenkins job that automatically executes a python script and launch its documentation via Sphinx.

The execution part works well but I'm not able to do the Sphinx part. My first idea was to create an 'Execute Windows Script bash' step inside the Jenkins job with `make html` command after going to the right directory with `cd`. But I keep on getting this error:

```
make is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Same idea works when I do it from the CMD tool. 
I already added the PATH variable in Jenkins settings with System32 folder.

System Information:

- OS: Windows
- Arch: x64

Comment: could you please add the system information, os and so on?

Comment: I am on windows 10 x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out, I just had to put the following inside my Windows Shell Job:

```
call "Path\To\make.bat"
```